# Any potential problem when both inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Concrete>` and a base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I seldom use multiple inheritance. And this is the first time I try to use ***multiple inheritance with `std::enable_shared_from_this`***.

I intend to ***use polymorphism***.

I am not sure is there any potential problem that I should be aware of?

Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Here is an example [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/hz5nMTTGW):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
 
struct Base{
    virtual ~Base(){std::cout << "~Base()" << std::endl;}
};
 
struct Concrete : public Base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Concrete> //mulitipule inheritance
{
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<Base> Create(){  //Please pay attention to the return type!
        return std::make_shared<Concrete>();
    };
    
    std::shared_ptr<Concrete> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
 
void testConcrete()
{
    // Concrete: the two shared_ptr's share the same object
    std::shared_ptr<Concrete> Concrete0 = std::make_shared<Concrete>();
    std::shared_ptr<Concrete> Concrete1 = Concrete0->getptr();
    std::cout << "Concrete1.use_count() = " << Concrete1.use_count() << '\n';
}
 
int main()
{
    testConcrete();
    std::cout << "============" << std::endl;
    auto sp = Concrete::Create();  //any potencial problem?
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. `std::make_shared<Concrete>()` creates `shared_ptr<Concrete>`, and that's what sets up the weak pointer that makes `shared_from_this()` work. That this `shared_ptr<Concrete>` is later converted to `shared_ptr<Base>` is irrelevant.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik “irrelevant"?You mean there is no petencial problem in the said convertation?Or it's not good to do such conversation in practice?

Comment: Yes, I mean there is no potential problem. By the time that conversion happens, `enable_shared_from_this` portion of `Concrete` is already correctly initialized. The conversion itself is fine, too.